# Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, cython

I was trying to compile a simple .pyx file using Cython.

```
print("hello")
```

Here's my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("hello.pyx")
)
```

Then I run the command.

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

The error is shown below. I've struggled on googling it but found nothing helpful.

> ```
>     running build_ext
>     building 'hello' extension
>     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD
> -IC:\Users\Jackie\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\Jackie\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\wdf\ucrt"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6\include\um"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared"
> "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tchello.c
> /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\hello.obj  
>     hello.c
>     c:\users\jackie\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(68):
> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or
> directory  
>     error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
> ```

Can someone help me to resolve the error, please?

I have Anaconda3 4.1.1, Python 3.5, and Visual Studio Express 2015 installed.

Comment: Well... the error went away after I uninstalled all Microsoft and python related software and install Anaconda and VS2015 Express again.
However, another error came along...

Answer (score 158):

> Update
>
> if you have Visual Studio 2022 no need to download VS Build Tools, as
> you can use for the same purpose Visual Studio Installer (located in
> VS2022 start menu folder)
>
> As pointed out by [JfredoJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988591/jfredoj)

You need windows 10 SDK,
Download [visual studio build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) and install

1. Visual C++ Build tools core features.
2. MSVC toolset C++ 2019 v142 (x86,x64)
3. Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable Update
4. Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0) for Desktop C++

[image: the image from Rivalus]

Comment: This did it for me! In particular the Windows 10 SDK for Desktop C++ was the key.

Comment: If you are using Windows Server 2016, you will need `Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for Desktop C++ [x86 and x64]` instead.

Comment: If you are on Windows 7, you will also need the "Windows 10 SDK" option selected.

Comment: The link is dead, try this instead: [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#title-129757)

Comment: official MS links in December 2019: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019

Comment: Did not help me. Still "Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory"

Comment: Did you restart your system ? @Dmitry

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated. I solved this problem like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56811119/3955129

Comment: All I needed was `Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019` redistributable

Comment: Your solution saved me!

Comment: 2.6GB for a header file..what a mess!

Comment: In my case only Windows 10 SDK was necessary. Also if you have Visual Studio 2022 no need to download VS Build Tools, as you can use for the same purpose `Visual Studio Installer` (located in VS2022 start menu folder).

Comment: `Windows 11 SDK` is needed?

Answer (score 31):

In case anyone finds this thread and is looking for a quicker solution than reinstalling VS and/or Anaconda - I was able to get past this same error by defining the environment variable **INCLUDE** pointing to the location of io.h - allowing the VS compiler to locate the header.

In my setup, using VS2015, the change to using the Universal CRT means the location of io.h is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\<version>\ucrt`. 
For different versions/environments the location of io.h may differ.

Comment: Could you clarify where you change this path? I'm using the "Visual C++ 2015 MSBuild Command Prompt"

Comment: @Atnas You should be able to use the `SET` command from within the prompt. Alternatively, if you want it to persist, you can set it via This PC/My Computer -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables and creating a new system wide variable.

Comment: This worked for me but then I got an errror: `cannot open include file: ‘Ws2_32.lib’` Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 24):

I stumbled upon the same problem - with very similar configuration to yours (only difference: VS 2015 Pro). After a few weeks on just having to download wheels from other people (e.g. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) I finally found a solution which works for me.

There are 2 problems. Problem 1 - you need to use "Developer Command Prompt" - sometimes there is such a program in Start Menu, then you just use it.

(BTW, for others: Python 3.5 needs VS2015, not any other version. Community edition is OK)

If not, you can use the following snippet (in command line):

```
"%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
```

or even:

```
where cl >nul 2>nul || "%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
```

(i have it in a batch file to run my build environment)

(If you dont have the `%VS140COMNTOOLS%` variable, then maybe you just installed the VS and you need e.g. to restart, so that new environment variables become visible).

Now you will get the error:

```
c:\program files\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(68): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

(as in your edited answer)

So now run:

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
```

OK, now you will get the error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrt.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
```

What now? You need to add library dirs:

```
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64
```

No errors this time:

```
> dir
05/16/2017  11:33 AM            69,240 hello.c
05/16/2017  11:47 AM            15,872 hello.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
05/16/2017  11:32 AM                17 hello.pyx
(...)
```

**TL;DR** - the whole thing:

```
where cl >nul 2>nul || "%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Comment: This was found here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/969047/cuda-8-vs2015-corecrt-h-error/?offset=7 - PyCUDA users have the same problem.

Comment: This solution was exactly what I was looking for. I have been trying for the longest time to solve this issue applying many different solutions. If you have problems running the `"%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"` with an error saying `"Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder."`, most likely you are using a laptop from your company and you have restricted access, you can verify by trying `reg query 1` and if it says `Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator.`, then that is the issue

Answer (score 14):

Microsoft doesn't make any effort to make console development steps obvious anymore.  Visual Studio has long been packaged with some batch files to establish environment variables.  When the C++ CLI development options are selected in VS2015/2017, there are one or more shortcuts added to the start menu to execute these batch files.

For VS 2017 the various batch files all call:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

with specific parameters.

Rather than setting a System or User Environment Variable, it would be better to call the specific batch file to meet your build needs.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat
```

One thing to bear in mind with Python/Ruby/etc, scripts will often need to elevate the execution shell to Administrator role in order to install packages.  If you execute the batch file in a non-Administrator shell, and the package installation requires elevation it will spawn a subshell which will not have the environment variables.  Therefore, you should run the batch file in an Administrator shell before calling the package manager or script.

Answer (score 12):

This is because Cython require libraries provided by Windows SDK.
To fix this, do the following:

1. Install Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019. Download from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).
   [image: Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019 download page]
2. Run VS Build Tools setup files (vs_buildtools.exe). Choose:

   - MSVC build tools (MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools)
   - Windows 10 SDK
     [image: Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019 installation]
3. Install VS Build Tools, it will require around 3 GB of space.
4. From Start Menu, run Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019.
   [image: Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019]
5. Go to your Cython development directory and then run: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Hopefully this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 10):

It can be solved by adding include dirs and library dirs as follow:

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt;E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\shared;E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\onecore\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64
```

```
set LIB=E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\onecore\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64
```

and if then you are now getting a problem: link error can run with rc.exe; 
you also need copy rc.exe and rc.dll (x64)  to the dir which is the same with the running `link.exe`

Comment: cant get why this answer so undervalued, only this brilliantly solve this trouble. thanks you so much!!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, solved it by installing Windows 10 SDK.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is running into this error while trying to install in `Git Bash` (I imagine this would also work for any `Bash` shell running on `Windows` using the `Visual Studio` compiler), then you can do the following:

```
INCLUDE="C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17763.0/ucrt/;C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.17763.0/shared/" \
> LIB="C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.17763.0/ucrt/x64;C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.17763.0/um/x64" \
> PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/bin/10.0.17763.0/x64 \
> python -m pip install <package>
```

For different versions of `Windows` and `Visual Studio` these paths may be slightly different. The best way to get them is when an error is thrown, search for the file with

```
find /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/ -name <name_of_error_causing_file>
```

Comment: Where exactly are we supposed to do this? I am using git bash and I'm not able to pip install some libraries.

Comment: Really really wish someone would answer this.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the items in the list posted by [bob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327578/bob), installing Universal CRT SDK solved the issue for me, so the list becomes:

1. Visual C++ Build tools core features.
2. VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64)
3. Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable Update
4. Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for Desktop C++
5. **Windows Universal CRT SDK**

Comment: You could just comment under his solution. This is more of a dublicate.

Comment: I wanted to, but it seems that I must have 50 reputations to be able to comment on his answer, and I don't have that many.

Comment: I needed more. I run Visual Studio Installer -> Visual Studio Build Tools 2019. It preselected: 
C++ BUILD TOOLS
C++ Build Tools core features
C++ 2019 Redistributable Update
C++ core desktop features
OPTIONAL
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.28)
Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)
C++ CMake tools for Windows
Testing tools core features - Build Tools
C++ AddressSanitizer (Experimental)
MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)
INDIVIDUAL COMPONENTS
Windows Universal CRT SDK
MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)

Comment: `Windows 11 SDK` is needed???

Answer (score 3):

**If installing the Build Tools didn't solve the problem, adding/editing 3 system environment variables will probably do**

*Depending on the versions of the build toold you installed, you might have to modify the paths a bit:*

1. Install [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/). I included the components `MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++-x64/x86-Buildtools` and `Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22000.0)`. The exact versions are probably not that important.
2. Add system environment variable `INCLUDE` with (adjust to your versions) value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\shared`. The first directory should contain e.g. `io.h` and `corecrt_wio.h`, the second should contain e.g. `basetsd.h`.
3. Add system environment variable `LIB` with value
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22000.0\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\x64`.
4. Add value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x86` to the system env. var. `Path`. This directory should contain `rcdll.dll` and `rc.exe`.
5. reboot system

As
[Felipe Araya Olea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory#comment118901402_43998080) pointed out, installing the Build Tools alone might not suffice due to restricted access to the registry when your e.g. working on a company computer. However, the above steps solved the problem for me.

Comment: THIS IS THE ONLY ANSWER, AMONG ALL THE OTHERS, THAT HELPED ME!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by adding the below packages in **Desktop development with C++**

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am in python and try to install fancy impute using pip install but i get the following error (Cannot open include file: 'io.h'). i am try to download windows SDK and add path to environmental variables but aslo failed

Comment: how can i fix it? i think it is the same error here

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error when trying to install `pyshark` and I resolved this issue by running `pip install pyshark` in `Developer Command Prompty for VS 2017` and making sure I had VC++ tools installed.

Answer (score 1):

Add windows 10 sdk in your environment path.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\\ucrt

1. apply the changes.
2. open a new command prompt with administrator rights.

the error should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall if you have installed any other "**Visual Studio Build Tools**" in you system.
2. Restart your system.
3. Download "**Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019**" from following URL and install it.
   URL : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019
   EXE : vs_buildtools__559949468.1570880854.exe
4. Restart your system.
5. Open CMD in admin mode, and try to install py packages. For me getting issues while installing **pyahocorasick** and **pyodbc** packages etc.
6. After installing above tool, check in your add remove program.
   [Screenshot of Add remove programs in Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QErOz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to transplant and build [pycocotools](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git) on Windows 10 with VS2017, and meet same error: "io.h not found".

To figure out why "io.h" was not found, the terminals output may give hints, i.e. how the including directory are specified. In my case, **wrong version of Windows 10 SDK is used:**

```
-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt
```

instead of

```
-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt
```

and there's no `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt` (but there is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0`).

Finally, in control panel, I removed `Windows Driver Kit 18362` (which was installed via VS2019 but VS2019 was removed later, and this 18362 is not totally uninstalled), and the problem "io.h not found" is solved.

---

Let me make it more clear:

- Windows SDK 10.0.17763.0 is introduced via VS2017
- Windows SDK 10.0.18362.0 is introduced via VS2019
  When there are multiple version of Windows SDK (even its directory not contains `ucrt` folder for including files), the newest one will be picked, which causing "io.h not found" similar error.

Answer (score 0):

check folder `d:\New folder` is accessible because Windows 10 SDK, Download Visual Studio Build tools needs that folder for temp files and errors are as described in these questions if it is not available.

Answer (score -2):

if anyone has any **issues with installing openstack or any other applications that require python or pip** (or netifaces, oslo.utils, python-cinderclient, msgpack, oslo.serialization, python-novaclient, PyYAML, pyperclip, colorama, pyreadline, attrs, wcwidth, cmd2, cliff, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, decorator, requestsexceptions, jsonpointer, jsonpatch, munch, jmespath, dogpile.cache, appdirs, OpenStack SDK, rfc3986, oslo.config, python-keystoneclient, osc-lib), and also that uses **Visual studio** - follow the below steps:

> 1. Install python 3.8.5
> 2. Pip is installed automatically with python
> 3. reboot the system (very important)
> 4. enter the cmd to install any app:  example: pip install python-openstackclient

Comment: This worked for me. Hope it works for others as well.

Answer (score -2):

I had this annoying error while I was trying to install pyhook 1.5.1.
It worked when I

1. install windows10 SDK (as I am using windows10)
2. run visual studio x64 command prompt in administrator mode.
3. take a cold shower.
4. Finally I press enter.

Yeasss! and it worked.