# Python package installation failed on windows 'io.h' / 'sys/mman.h' : No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I'm on windows 10 and trying to install mrpt for python (3.5). 
`pip install git+https://github.com/teemupitkanen/mrpt/` returns

```
c:\python35\include\pyconfig.h(68): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Tried to launch `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` as it said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cython-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory).  It added the file `io.h` file in the folder `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\include` that i added to the system path. But i still have the same error, when lauching `pip install ...`

I also tried to launch the `pip install ...` from the **Visual c++ 2015 x86 x64 Cross Build Tools Command Prompt** but now, i have another error

```
cpp/mrptmodule.cpp(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/mman.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Don't know what to do. Any help