# pyconfig.h - Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, anaconda, visual-studio-2017

#### Background:

- I am new to python/Cpp and I am trying to install a python package python-crfsuite which needs to VS to compile.
- I have installed Anaconda3, pyhon3.6 all in VS2017 community installer (because I think it is better because I will use compiler of VS: `cl.exe`)
- I have already run `vcvarsall.bat`
- All commands I run are in admin

#### Process:

When I trying to `pip install` python-crfsuite, it gives me the error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icrfsuite/include/ -Icrfsuite/lib/cqdb/include -Iliblbfgs/include -Ipycrfsuite -Icrfsuite/win32 -Iinclude "-IC:\Program Files\Anaconda3\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Anaconda3\include" /EHsc /Tppycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pycrfsuite/_pycrfsuite.obj
    _pycrfsuite.cpp
    c:\program files\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.10.25017\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

- I have read the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cython-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory). So I try to replace the path in my system environment as following:

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x86`

  =>

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x86`

  but it doesnt do anything for me.
- Then I try to download `io.h` and place in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include` but it is useless.
- Finally I try to use conda install `conda install -c conda-forge python-crfsuite` and it is **success**

#### Question

- Why `conda install` dose not have the problem with `io.h`, any difference with `pip install` ?
- Why there are multiple `cl.exe` in different path in VS (I am not so familiar with) and are there any difference in using different `cl.exe`?

I ask these question because even if I installed Anaconda, if I want to use pip install, I have to face these problems and I still cannot figure it out

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error but I was installing a package. I solved installing more tools from Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2017 Community and Python 3.6.4). I installed those tools (see installer screenshot [here](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/03/incredibuild.png)):

1. **Desktop development with C++:** I included all defaulted items and the next ones:

   - Windows XP support for C++
   - Support for C++/CLI
   - VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset
2. **Linux development with C++**

Then I opened the **Windows PowerShell** as *Administrator privilegies* (Right click to open) and move folder of Visual Studio installation and find that path:

```
cd [Visual Studio Path]\VC\Auxiliary\Build
```

Then I executed this file:

```
.\vcvars32.bat
```

After that I use pip as normal, for instance, I wanted to install *Mayavi*:

```
pip install mayavi
```

I hope that it helps someone too.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, but for me only `VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset` was necessary to build [this library](https://github.com/bcdev/jpy) for example (They probably didn't make it compatible with VS2017 build tools).

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Windows 10 `'io.h'` comes with any `'SDK for Windows 10'` in visual studio installer (my SDK ver 10.0.20348.0 resolve problem)