# Error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2. While installing Spacy

Tags: visual-studio, spacy

I am trying to install Spacy on windows 10 which is of 64 bit. I have Python 3.6.4 64 bit, Visual Studio 14 is installed. but I am getting below error, I have added Image as well of the error

Error code:
`error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
[image: Error Screen shot]

Comment: please check to see if it's duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cython-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2):

So I tried couple of thing to resolve this Error, finally I had to create an Conda environment and try installing spacy in conda environment with Python 3.6 version which was successful.
or trying downloading Visual studio Build tools for 17(Visual C++ 17 is required for Python 3,6 version), which may resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Download required python module from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) and run:

```
pip install file_name.whl
```

Comment: For the non-initiate (e.g. me) this needs more explanation. Why does this help?