# Updating Anaconda fails: Environment Not Writable Error

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to update Anaconda and its packages using `conda update --name root conda`, but it fails every time.

> Error message : EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not
>   have write permissions to the target environment. environment
>   location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

Environment location: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`. I replaced the `root` with `base`, still I get the same error.

Any help?

Comment: Maybe you could give some more details about your environment and the versions of software that might be pertinent to the question to help anyone who might be able to help you.

Comment: In addition, in more recent versions of conda (for the last 1.5 years or so) the main environment is called `base`, not `root`.

Comment: environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3.
I replaced the root with base. I get the same error

Comment: If using windows 10, open terminal with "Run as administrator"

Comment: When installing packages, this error can occur if you have forgot to first activate your environment. (Not your issue exactly but it may help other people with who have that issue and find this question.)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

start your command prompt with run as administrator

Comment: This is not correct. At least under Linux/Mac OS conda is not supposed to require super user rights.

Comment: It worked well for me. Could you explain why your solution is worked?

Comment: It worked for me on Windows 10. I haven't tried on Mac, but I would try running the command as sudo conda update --name root conda.

Comment: @hamedbaziyad yes, it might be considered as workaround and might solve your problem, but running conda with super user rights should not be necessary in many cases and is probably not the best thing to do in these cases. Running commands with super user rights can cause more damage than without, so it is always better to avoid super user rights. Also users might not have super user rights but still want to update conda.

Comment: It worked for me . Only after doing this ,  I can get my Spyder IDE ,updated to the latest version....

Comment: For Linux/Mac: see answers by @Sushanth or lumbric (me), this answer here is wrong. Conda does not necessarily require root access to install software.

Comment: On Windows, if you're trying to install packages into the `base` environment (which is installed to `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`), you'll need admin access. If you first create an environment (which should install in your user directory under .conda\envs) and activate it, you no longer need admin right for that environment. Don't forget to activate the env after creating it.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: This works. But how to do this from the terminal *within VS Code*?

Answer (score 83):

If you face this issue in Linux, one of the common reasons can be that the folder "anaconda3" or "anaconda2" has root ownership. This prevents other users from writing into the folder.
This can be resolved by changing the ownership of the folder from root to "USER" by running the command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER anaconda3
```

or `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER <path of anaconda 3/2 folder>`

Note: How to figure out whether a folder has root ownership?
-- There will be a lock symbol on the top right corner of the respective folder.
Or right-click on the folder->properties and you will be able to see the owner details

The -R argument lets the $USER access all the folders and files within the folder anaconda3 or anaconda2 or any respective folder. It stands for "recursive".

Comment: Worked for me. However, I think you need to change the ownership of ~/.conda as well since it contains, for example, environments.txt which needs to be updated.

Comment: sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP <path of anaconda 3/2 folder>

Comment: Where is the anaconda folder typically located? If you are on a computer shared with other people, such as a server, is this solution really recommended?

Answer (score 64):

On Windows, search for **Anaconda PowerShell Prompt**. Right click the program and select **Run as administrator**. In the command prompt, execute the following command:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Your Anaconda should now update without admin related errors.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: Running the update command in the administrator mode solved the issue here

Comment: Can you tell me why, when I run  conda update -n base -c defaults conda it says Warning: A newer version of conda exists please run  conda update -n base -c defaults conda?  Keeps me amused for hours....

Answer (score 32):

Open this folder "C:\ProgramData\" and right-click on "\Anaconda3". go to properties -> security and check all the boxes for each user. This worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too while using miniconda

Comment: @Anthony you have to be an admin to make those changes.

Comment: Easy solution that works (should you be administrator)

Answer (score 26):

If you get this error under Linux when running conda using sudo, you might be suffering from bug [#7267](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7267#issuecomment-387329419):

When logging in as non-root user via sudo, e.g. by:

```
sudo -u myuser -i
```

conda seems to assume that it is run as root and raises an error.

The only known workaround seems to be: Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
unset SUDO_UID SUDO_GID SUDO_USER
```

...or unset the ENV variables by running the line in a different way before running conda.

If you [mistakenly installed anaconda/miniconda as root/via sudo](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7267#issuecomment-498651734) this can also lead to the same error, then you might want to do the following:

```
sudo chown -R username /path/to/anaconda3
```

*Tested with conda 4.6.14.*

Answer (score 17):

On Windows in general, running command prompt with administrator works. But if you don't want to do that every time, specify *Full control* permissions of your user (or simply all users) on Anaconda3 directory. Be aware that specifying it for all users allows other users to install their own packages and modify the content.

[image: Permissions example]

Comment: Only Windows solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

I had installed anaconda via the system installer on OS X in the past, which created a `~/.conda/environments.txt` owned by root. Conda could not modify this file, hence the error.

To fix this issue, I changed the ownership of that directory and file to my username:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.conda
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and the `base` environment was in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`. This is the case, when Anaconda is installed `for all users`.

As a **solution**, I re-installed Anaconda `just for me` and now the `base` environment is in `\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3`. This now can be updated via `conda update` without admin privileges.

Comment: I believe this answer is out of date.  I installed only for local user (myself) not all users and I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, I would suggest looking at your conda config file.

**Reason**

Sometimes for creating a virtual env at a specified location other than the pre-defined path at `~/anaconda3/envs` we append the conda config file using: `conda config --append envs_dirs /path/to/envs` where `envs_dirs` is a specified function in config file for allocating different paths where conda can find your virtual envs. Removing a recently added path in this config file may solve the problem.

**Solution**

```
$:> conda config --show envs_dirs

    envs_dirs:
    - /home/some_recent_path    # remove this
    - /home/.../anaconda3/envs
```

Note the *value* specifing a different directory other than the predefined location, and *remove* it using

```
$:> conda config --remove envs_dirs /home/some_recent_path
```

Now the config file `envs_dirs` is set to default location of envs. Try creating a new env now.

Comment: On Windows 11, running Conda as admin solved package installation failure issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows,

1. Create a new environment with

   `conda create --name py35 python=3.5`

[see conda cheat sheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf)

2. Activate this environment

   `conda activate py35`
3. Now you don't need to have root access to your new environment.

As mentioned in a comment to the accepted answer, the **default environment** `base` requires administrative rights on Windows:

> On Windows, if you're trying to install packages into the base
> environment (which is installed to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3), you'll
> need admin access. If you first create an environment (which should
> install in your user directory under .conda\envs) and activate it, you
> no longer need admin right for that environment. Don't forget to
> activate the env after creating it. –  C.J. Jackson

Comment: This is a got approach, and works for me, but take care, that on VS Code, sometimes it says that conda env is loaded but not. Restarting VS Code make my problem to go away.

Answer (score 3):

this line of code on your terminal, solves the problem

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER anaconda 3
```

Comment: For linux users only

Answer (score 2):

**WINDOWS:**
I also got following error while `(base) PS E:\Python> conda install ConfigParser`

Verifying transaction: failed

EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

My solution: Open Command prompt as administrator, then above command again and it worked.

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install ConfigParser
>
> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment: done
>
> Package Plan
>
> environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
>
> added / updated specs:
> - configparser
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> configparser       pkgs/main/noarch::configparser-5.0.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done Executing
> transaction: done

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The cause for me was that when downloading Anaconda, I chose 'download for all users' instead of 'just for me'. I uninstalled it, re-installed it and corrected that. And I'm not getting this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In my case somehow **CONDA_ENVS_PATH** was removed, so I was having NotWritableError. So I fixed the error by specifying

```
CONDA_ENVS_PATH=~/my-envs:/opt/anaconda/envs
```

in the .bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

I was also suffered by same problem. I resolved the problem by reinstalling anaconda(While installation at this time I selected "just for me" as user) and my problem was solved.Try the same

Answer (score 0):

CONDA UPDATE - NO WRITE ACCESS PROBLEM ## FIXED##

SIMPLE SOLUTION:

1. Press the Windows+S combination button and type "cmd" into it.
2. Right click on the *Command Prompt* App result that shows up and click on "Run as administrator"
3. Now, in the black window that is open (i.e. your Command prompt), copy and paste the following to check for your version: `conda --version`
4. If you want the latest update, then update Conda by running the update command by pasting the following and clicking enter  in the command prompt(black window):
   `conda update conda`
5. If a newer version is available, it will prompt you for a yes/no to install the update. Type "yes" and then press *Enter* to update.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Anaconda Navigator to always run as administrator on Windows 10 by following these steps

Right-click on the Anaconda Navigator icon and select “Properties”.
Click on the “Compatibility” tab.
Check the box next to “Run this program as an administrator”.
Click “Apply” and then click “OK”.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to install **pyLDAvis** with the following code in **Anaconda Prompt**.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyLDAvis
```

I ran the **Anaconda Prompt** in **Administrator mode** (run as administrator) and executed the code again. It was installed successfully!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I would suggest **NOT** manually tamper the permission list like the other answers suggest, as the permission of this directory by default is already allowing every user to write to this path, encountering this error is most likely because user (you or another user) have previously modified the permission list by mistake, and what we should do is to restore the original permissions rather than adding more entries.

Open the properties dialog of the corresponding folder of your conda distribution.

- Anaconda: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`
- Miniconda: `C:\tools\mambaforge`

Navigate to Security - Advanced

An example of wrongly configured directory permissions shown below. (which is the case from myself)

The `Inherited from` field is `None` in this case indicating the permission has been manually modified. And `User` have no `Modify` permission to write to this folder.

Click the `Enable inheritance` button on the bottom left to restore original permissions from parent folder, and remove any entries whose `Inherited from` is `None`.

[image: mambaforge folder permissions]

If done correctly, the folder permission should look like this.

[image: correct mambaforge folder permissions]

run your `conda` commands now, and permission error should be gone.

Answer (score -2):

Deleting file .condarc (eg./root/.condarc) in the user's home directory before installation, resolved the issue.

Comment: This is a bad idea: won't work for most people most of the time, and could remove some necessary configuration options.