# EnvironmentNotWritableError on Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to get python-utils package and utils module work in my anaconda3. However, whenever I open my Anaconda Powershell and try to install the package it fails with the comment

> EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
> environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

I searched for solutions and was advised that I update conda.
However, when I ran the comment below

> conda update -n base -c defaults conda

it also failed with EnvironmentNotWritableError showing.

Then I found a comment that says maybe my conda isn't installed at some places, so I tried

> conda install conda

which got the same error.

Then I tried

> conda install -c conda-forge python-utils

which also failed with the same error.

Maybe it's the problem with setting paths? but I don't know how to set them. All I know about paths is that I can type

> sys.path

and get where Anaconda3 is running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating Anaconda fails: Environment Not Writable Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290271/updating-anaconda-fails-environment-not-writable-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the PowerShell as Administrator. Right Click on the PowerShell -> Choose to Run as Administrator. Then you'll be able to install the required packages.

Comment: thank you so much! I was able to update conda and download python-utils package after running PowerShell as administrator!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. python-uitls and utils are separate modules

Comment: It doesn help for me ;(

Answer (score 4):

I have got the same non writable error in anaconda prompt for downloading pandas,then sorted the the error by running anaconda prompt as administrator. it worked for me since i already had that path variable in environment path