# Unable to update conda in Pycharm

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, conda

I am trying to update conda in Pycharm through commands, but I get this error.

```
EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target 
environment.

environment location: /opt/miniconda3
uid: 1000
gid: 1000
```

I checked ownership of the folder and confirmed that user was the owner, rather than root. How do I fix this error?

Note, I am on Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating Anaconda fails: Environment Not Writable Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290271/updating-anaconda-fails-environment-not-writable-error)

Answer (score 0):

try running in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/miniconda3
```

Comment: Thank your for the response. I thought what i did earlier (sudo chown user:user file/path) was good enough. Thanks.