# How to use Geoplot in Azure Functions (GEOS/PROJ issue)

Tags: python, azure, proj, geos, geoplot

I've been trying to build a python Azure function which requires Geoplot. However, when I try to deploy it I get an error message, likely due to GEOS/PROJ. Here's part of the output:

> - Downloading Cartopy-0.20.1.tar.gz (10.8 MB)
> - Installing build dependencies: started
> - Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
> - Getting requirements to build wheel: started
> - ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> - Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
> - command: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.12/bin/python3.8 /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp8ki7x3mh
> - cwd: /tmp/pip-install-q5qyetv4/cartopy
> - Complete output (3 lines):
> - setup.py:117: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.7.2 or later installed, or installation may fail.
> - warnings.warn(
> - Proj 8.0.0 must be installed.
> - ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.12/bin/python3.8 /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp8ki7x3mh Check the logs for full command output.

How can I use Geoplot in an Azure function?

Comment: Hello @Tuk31n, Do you have installed latest version of GEOS and Proj ..?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have the latest versions installed on my local but it seems I can't install them when deploying the function.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I try to deploy it I get an error message, likely due to
> GEOS/PROJ.

Here are few of workaround to check

- Please make sure that you have installed [GEOS/PROJ](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1239#issuecomment-445576627) in your local .
- If you have Anaconda in your local  try the below `cmdlt`  to install it

```py
conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
```

For more information please refer below links:

SO THREAD:  [Install Cartopy & dependencies on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001347/install-cartopy-dependencies-on-windows)

MS DOC: [Transform relational data with Pandas and Azure Function Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-serverless-cloud-etl-04) .