# Installing Cartopy error on Windows 10 with VSCode

Tags: python, cmake, cartopy, geos

I al trying to install Cartopy on my laptop. I have Windows 10, and use VSCode.

When installing Cartopy with `pip install cartopy`I get the following error:

```
lib/cartopy/trace.cpp(767): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'geos_c.h': No such file or directory
   error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I installed shapely, matplotlib and pygeos beforehands, but somehow it doesn't seem to do the trick.

I then tried to install GEOS, but didnt succeed, apparently you have to use CMAKE to install it correctly but htet didn't work. (still get the same error)

is it possible to install it without installing Anaconda ? (I have seen that a lot online)

Any help/advice please would help me greatly.

Comment: if you do go with conda, I would strongly recommend [`miniforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) or [`mambaforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge). Both of these packages install the `conda` package manager, but Anaconda installs a large number of packages from the `deafults` channel into your base environment, which can cause problems down the road. conda is definitely the recommended approach here, so using it would probably save you time. but if you really don't want to install conda, you could try `pipwin`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Cartopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74293754/cant-install-cartopy)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify where you have GEOS installed, so that cartopy can compile the wheels.
You can install [osgeo](https://www.osgeo.org/projects/osgeo4w/), and then use `pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-LC:/OSGeo4W/lib" --global-option="-IC:/OSGeo4W/include" cartopy==0.21.0` to install cartopy.

Just keep in mind to install Shapely between 1.6.4 and 1.8.4. Cartopy seems to have conflicts with the latest shapely release.

- Update: Passing GEOS headers might not work directly on pip. If that is the case, you might have to clone [cartopy repo](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy.git), and install it manually:

```
git clone https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy.git

cd cartopy

python setup.py build_ext -LC:\OSGeo4W\lib -IC:\OSGeo4W\include

python setup.py install
```