# Struggling to Install Cartopy

Tags: python, pip, cartopy

I'm struggling to Install Cartopy from the Terminal and from Pycharm.

This is what I get as error message:

```
 1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Cartopy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Cartopy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Can someone please help with the problem. Thanks

I tried to Update the Pip Install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Cartopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74293754/cant-install-cartopy)

Comment: No it doesnt. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error on macOS 12.6, and I solved it by installing *geos* before installing *cartopy* with *pip*.

```
brew install geos
```

It is based on an answer at GitHub [Unable to install cartopy using pip #535](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/535)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions since you didn't specify the OS you are using or the full error log.

If on a Linux and the error log is due to `geos_c.h is not found.`
Install the developer version of the geos library

```
sudo apt install libgeos-dev
```

as can be seen from [here](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1940).

If you are on a mac or windows, you may use `conda` to install it. find the installation instruction miniconda [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) then

```
conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
```