# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, geopandas, fiona

I'm working with polygon data in Python and am having trouble importing packages fiona and geopandas. When I run:

import fiona

I receive the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5540\1102285635.py in <module>
----> 1 import fiona

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py in <module>
     83 
     84 import fiona._loading
---> 85 with fiona._loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():
     86     from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
     87     from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I've seen suggestions online that this is the result of incompatibilities between certain versions of packages, but as far as I can tell I've set my packages to the correct versions:

- fiona: 1.8.22
- geopandas: 0.9.0
- Shapely: 1.8.5 (tried 2.0.0 as well)
- GDAL: 3.4.1

Comment: since you're using anaconda, it's extremely likely this is the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74295187/3888719. The issue isn't package versions, but *channels*. conda channels are the package sources - each channel maintains internally-consistent versions of compilers and non-python binary dependencies. mixing and matching them can lead to badness. don't use anaconda - use [`miniforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge).

Comment: @MichaelDelgado what is your recommendation on solving this problem? Is it to create the same env but using miniforge/mambaforge to install the packages?