# Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory. Python3.7.x Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I am trying to install packages with pip. Using python 3.7.x on Windows 10 produces this error: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory.

When using python 3.6 no error occures.

I am using the latest standalone version of VisualC++ from [visualstudio.microsoft.com](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fdevblogs.microsoft.com%2Fcppblog%2Fannouncing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments%2F#title-43651)

Comment: which package are you trying to install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cython- Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cython-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+Cannot+open+include+file+io.h+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: I was installing a bunch of packages via "pip install -r file.txt". I was going to reproduce the error today (one day later) to find out which packages was the one that coulnd find the "io.h" file but i couldnt ... To my surprise everything was working like it should with python 3.7.x. I did not change a thing. And yes i restarted the system before too. Thanks for the help anyways! Much love

Comment: Should this Question be deleted ?