# pip install web3 not installing

Tags: python, pip, web3py

any advice would be greatly appreciated. I have installed visual studio like it tells me in the error and I have also attempted to pip install this in a venv environment however its still not working I have included the full error message below.

The error message is a little long this is the last message it gives         `error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2` as mentioned I have already installed visual studio so I do not understand I have looked into it being a env variable that I need to create to no avalie it sounds like theirs a missing folder by the looks of the error, if so how do I go about fixing this?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\carl-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\carl-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\carl-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gzs5afno' --python-tag cp37
           cwd: C:\Users\carl-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\lru-dict\
      Complete output (11 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" /Tclru.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\lru.obj
      lru.c
      c:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
      Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
      Building wheel for cytoolz (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\carl-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\\cytoolz\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\carl-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\\cytoolz\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\carl-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-a6zbn7gs' --python-tag cp37
           cwd: C:\Users\carl-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\cytoolz\
      Complete output (55 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\utils_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\curried
      copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\curried
      copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\curried
      copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\curried
      copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cytoolz\tests
      running build_ext
      building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cytoolz
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" /Tccytoolz/dicttoolz.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cytoolz/dicttoolz.obj
      dicttoolz.c
      c:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cytoolz
      Running setup.py clean for cytoolz
    Failed to build lru-dict cytoolz
    Installing collected packages: lru-dict, cytoolz, eth-utils, attrdict, hexbytes, parsimonious, eth-abi, eth-keys, eth-keyfile, rlp, eth-rlp, eth-account, web3
      Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\carl-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\carl-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\carl-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-89q4z0xh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
             cwd: C:\Users\carl-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\lru-dict\
        Complete output (11 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_ext
        building 'lru' extension
        creating build
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" /Tclru.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\lru.obj
        lru.c
        c:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\carl-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\carl-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pdkcfk2e\\lru-dict\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\carl-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-89q4z0xh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-manag
```

ed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: It seems like you're using python3.7, can you try ```pip3 install ...``` instead of ```pip install ...```

Comment: hummm  thank you for the suggestion I just gave "pip3 install web3" ago but it resulted in the same error unfortunately.

Comment: If I use pip3 does this also mean I need to downgrade my python version to 3? I just took a look at https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py and it says it suppports Python 3.6+

Comment: no pip3 is for any Python3+ be it 3.5 or 3.7. 

Also, you have python3.7 installed so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, I just gave it ago on python3.6 just in case 3.7 isnt working for web3. Would you happen to have any idear on how else I might fix the error?

Comment: Im having a look. You also don't need VS Code installed since my docker doesn't have VS code. Do you have docker?

Comment: Can you actually run the command as admin? In mac/linux ```sudo pip install web3```

Comment: https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/121#issuecomment-307357852

Comment: @daudnadeem `pip` already seems to be correctly pointing to the version associated with `python 3.7`, so no need to run `pip3`. OP is also obviously on windows, so `sudo` commands will not work. The github link you have posted is a) for a completely different lib, b) a different error and c) has 200 downvotes and probably rather useless to fix an error where a certain header cannot be found

Comment: Thank you once again,  ahh I see wont be using that respiratory so to make sure I understand are you saying it isnt somthing I can fix? Thanks

Comment: Manged to get it working by install all of the VS packages thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is

```
c:\users\carl-\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
```

What `pip` is doing here is downloading the `web3` source and trying to compile it using the compiler that came with your visual studio in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio`

It fails, because it cannot find headers which come bundled with the `Windows SDK` (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cython-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)) which you can install using the `Visual Studio Installer`. Simply select "Modify" and then "Individual Components" and install the "Windows 10 SDK". That should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for the help, I just Modified visual studio and installed "Visual studio SDK" and Windows 10 SDK (10.0. 16299.0) however after restarting I am still getting the same error. Is their any other things from VS I should also try installing? 

Thanks

Comment: For me, `io.h` is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt` after installing the `10.0.16299.0 SDK`, could you check if that folder exists for you as well?

Comment: ohhh how intresting yes it does! below is the code inside the io.h

#pragma once
#define _INC_IO

   #include <corecrt_io.h>

Comment: Manged to get it working by installing just able everything inside VS Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

just install cython

```
pip install cython #in the same environment
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if my problem was the same, but downloading Microsoft C++ build tools worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30261897)

Comment: This was not a bad answer and worked for me. I would suggest to add the version of the build tools that worked for you and maybe other details like you need a microsoft account in order to access the download and add a link to the download form or page.

Answer (score -4):

On Windows 10, I tried to install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools, but that didn't solve the problem. So I installed a Linux-based system instead, used it as dual boot, and it works.

Comment: ...not really useful answer for people that need to use Windows.