# Can pip install webrtcvad on windows 10?

Tags: python, pip

I have been trying to set up a voice cloning project found on github (https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning)

and I have been unable to find anything on Google which helps me to resolve the issue im experiencing.

Essentially; the command `pip install webrtcvad` does not work. The reason im doing this is because following the instructions to simply install all the packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt` doesnt work either, so im going through and installing the listed packages one at a time.

i get this error in the terminal (im using anaconda due to failures to make this work directly with python)

```
  Running setup.py clean for webrtcvad
  Running command 'C:\Users\aekna\Anaconda3\envs\python 3.7\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aekna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i6tao_v0\\webrtcvad\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aekna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i6tao_v0\\webrtcvad\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
  running clean
  removing 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.7' (and everything under it)
  removing 'build\lib.win-amd64-3.7' (and everything under it)
  'build\bdist.win-amd64' does not exist -- can't clean it
  'build\scripts-3.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
  removing 'build'
Failed to build webrtcvad
Installing collected packages: webrtcvad
  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\aekna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-129vj19v
    Running command 'C:\Users\aekna\Anaconda3\envs\python 3.7\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aekna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i6tao_v0\\webrtcvad\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aekna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i6tao_v0\\webrtcvad\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aekna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-129vj19v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying webrtcvad.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_webrtcvad' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\webrtc
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\webrtc\common_audio
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\webrtc\common_audio\signal_processing
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\webrtc\common_audio\vad
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWEBRTC_POSIX -Icbits "-IC:\Users\aekna\Anaconda3\envs\python 3.7\include" "-IC:\Users\aekna\Anaconda3\envs\python 3.7\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /Tccbits\pywebrtcvad.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\pywebrtcvad.obj
    pywebrtcvad.c
    c:\users\aekna\anaconda3\envs\python 3.7\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    Running setup.py install for webrtcvad ... error
Cleaning up...
  Removing source in C:\Users\aekna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i6tao_v0\webrtcvad
Removed build tracker 'C:\\Users\\aekna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-k4jqyw56'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\aekna\Anaconda3\envs\python 3.7\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aekna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i6tao_v0\\webrtcvad\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aekna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i6tao_v0\\webrtcvad\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aekna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-129vj19v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

please do note that while i have some experience in other languages; i am completely new to python.

Comment: You are missing the relevant parts of the output, which would have occurred before the single line you posted.

Comment: @jordanm i edited the post but can you please maybe tell me what the relevant lines might look like? im not sure; very new to python stuff.

Comment: This is the relevant line: `c:\users\aekna\anaconda3\envs\python 3.7\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50210015/9440595

Comment: I had a similar problem on Windows while installing webrtcvad~=2.0.10 and I solved it by installing "Windows 10 SDK" via Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: Here is a tutorial to install it: https://poorlydocumented.com/2019/11/installing-corentinjs-real-time-voice-cloning-project-on-windows-10-from-scratch/