# Install pycocotools error "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "C:\Program.obj""

Tags: python, visual-studio, pycocotools

I'm trying to train tensorflow model using this tutorial `https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-your-own-object-detector-ad69dda69c85` but when I'm trying to install pycocotools I get following error:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.1
6.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Ja
\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I.
./common -IC:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users
\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Mic
rosoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.
16.27023\include" /Tcpycocotools/_mask.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyc
ocotools/_mask.obj
_mask.c
c:\users\ja\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal
 error C1083: Cannot open file include: 'io.h': No such file or directory

error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Communit
y\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit sta
tus 2
```

I've tried installing Visual Studio 2017 packages suggested in this thread `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory`
but this still doesn't work. Any ideas what is wrong?

Pycocotools from `https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi`

Windows 8.1

Python 3.7

Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Do you have the Visual C++ 2015 build tools on your path? Just making sure you followed the readme on https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi

Comment: What do you mean "on your path"?

Comment: (I'm referring to what the GitHub page says you should do to install it properly.) Google: "Add Path to Environment Variables" Read this for what it is: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/simple-questions-what-are-environment-variables