# Cannot install "blist" in order to install ElastAlert

Tags: python, windows, pip, elastalert

I am trying to install ElastAlert. I have tried both ways described in their documentation:

1: Installing via pip: pip install elastalert

The installation fails when trying to install "blist".

2: Cloning the repo, installing the setup.py file with python setup.py install

The script fails when trying to install "blist".

So then I have tried to install "blist" separately with:

pip install blist, which fails.

and I downloaded the .exe installation file for "blist" which opens and tells me I do need Python 2.6 to install it. I have 3.8.1 installed so that should not really be the problem right?

I am at the end of tether here and would really appreciate some help :)

Error when trying pip install elastalert:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\matthias.reichenberg\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f99484f4\blist\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f99484f4\blist\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-9o0odm_c'
       cwd: C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f99484f4\blist\

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for blist
  Running setup.py clean for blist
Failed to build blist

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\matthias.reichenberg\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f99484f4\blist\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f99484f4\blist\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-we1u1k_w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\matthias.reichenberg\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\blist'
         cwd: C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f99484f4\blist\
    Complete output (19 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blist
    copying blist_btuple.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blist
    copying blist_sorteddict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blist
    copying blist_sortedlist.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blist
    copying blist__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blist
    running build_ext
    building 'blist._blist' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\blist
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DBLIST_FLOAT_RADIX_SORT=1 -Ic:\users\matthias.reichenberg\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\matthias.reichenberg\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" /Tcblist/_blist.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\blist/_blist.obj
    _blist.c
    c:\users\matthias.reichenberg\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\matthias.reichenberg\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f99484f4\blist\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f99484f4\blist\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\matthias.reichenberg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-we1u1k_w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\matthias.reichenberg\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\blist' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: What error message do you get when you run `pip install elastalert` ?

Comment: I've installed it right now using `python3.7.6` on Ubuntu 18.04... I don't think the problem within the python3.

Comment: @Keri I have included the error message in the post above

Comment: Try to install `python-dev` package. I am facing the same issue installing blist on RHEL7 so i tried installing `python-devel` yum packages and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:
`Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory error`

Try this:
[Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Tried that. The error did not get resolved or change :(