# Git Bash : Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, anaconda, windows-10, conda, git-bash

Before you report this as duplicate, I am asking this question specifically for Git bash.

[This link answers the question, but not for git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

I understand that I need to download [Visual studio build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019) and install Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for Desktop C++.

I did all these steps but I keep getting the error when using git bash. I tried opening the developer command prompt for VS 2019 and entering the following:

```
set INCLUDE="C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/ucrt/;C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/shared/" \ 
set LIB="C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.18362.0/ucrt/x64;C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.18362.0/um/x64" \
set PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/bin/10.0.18362.0/x64 \
```

It doesn't seem to help, and I know thats because the git bash shell isn't able to read that. How exactly do I permanently set this so that I can run conda virtual environments and pip install libraries using git bash?

Comment: _How exactly do I permanently set this so that I can run conda virtual environments and pip install libraries using git bash?_ Is that the final goal? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes I want to be able to 'pip install' in virtual conda environments without getting the "cannot find io.h" error message.