# ‘pip install pybullet’ causes error “cannot open input file ‘Ws2_32.lib’”

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, pybullet

When `pip install pybullet` is entered into the command prompt, the wheel fails to build and “errors out with exit status 1” then after a long list of red text it says: `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file ‘Ws2_32.lib’` before trying and failing to build the wheel again with the same error. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

My first problems were the same as the ones in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory) but I resolved those by adding the file locations to the path. I was going to try the same solution with this problem but I could not find `Ws2_32` on the computer. I think this has something to do with it being an input file. There are several files named `WS2_32` (where the *s* is capitalized) that are in similar places to the other files I needed to add to `PATH` but adding them to the path or `LIB` does not change anything. I have tried most of the solutions I have found online, though there are not many. I just do not know how to make sure the computer can find a file that I can’t. Does this mean I just don’t have it? Is there anywhere I can download it? I have also restarted the computer several times.

I have installed `pybullet` successfully on another computer and I have tried to make my Visual Studio installation look similar (pybullet requires Visual Studio).
I am using Python 3.6 64bit, Pip is upgraded, and Windows 7. The only difference that I think might matter between the two computers is that the successful one runs Windows 10. I can provide more information if it is needed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I installed pybullet in VS Code without wheel installed and it gets installed successfully.
Maybe try installing it without using wheel.

Comment: Running `pip install pybullet —no-binary :all:` (skips wheel) throws same error during `installing setup.py`. Did you mean I had to use a special VS tool?