# Error installing fastparquet in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, fastparquet

I am trying to install `fastparquet` in `Anaconda` on `Windows 10`. I tried fixing the expected errors by installing `Visual Studio Build Tools` by following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Steps taken when installing Build Tools:

1. Visual C++ Build tools core features.
2. VC++ 2017 v141 toolset (x86,x64)
3. Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable Update
4. Windows 10 SDK (10.0.16299.0) for Desktop C++

Error link provided in the error message related to Numpy

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html

I have tried all possible solutions and I am stuck at these error messages.

```
(base) C:\Users\murta>pip install fastparquet
Collecting fastparquet
  Downloading fastparquet-0.4.1.tar.gz (28.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 28.6 MB 3.3 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.19 in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numba>=0.28 in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (0.48.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: thrift>=0.11.0 in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fastparquet) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->fastparquet) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.19->fastparquet) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite<0.32.0,>=0.31.0dev0 in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.28->fastparquet) (0.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.28->fastparquet) (45.2.0.post20200210)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\murta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from packaging->fastparquet) (2.4.6)
Building wheels for collected packages: fastparquet
  Building wheel for fastparquet (setup.py) ... / ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\murta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ir1pub43\\fastparquet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\murta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ir1pub43\\fastparquet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\murta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-re7pe_xn'
       cwd: C:\Users\murta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ir1pub43\fastparquet\
  Complete output (85 lines):
  Compiling fastparquet/speedups.pyx because it depends on C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.pxd.
  [1/1] Cythonizing fastparquet/speedups.pyx
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\compression.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\converted_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\dataframe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\encoding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\schema.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\thrift_structures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\writer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  copying fastparquet\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\fastparquet
  running egg_info
  writing fastparquet.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to fastparquet.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to fastparquet.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to fastparquet.egg-info\top_level.txt
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\murta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ir1pub43\fastparquet\setup.py", line 98, in <module>
      **extra
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 53, in run
      self.build_package_data()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 118, in build_package_data
      for package, src_dir, build_dir, filenames in self.data_files:
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 66, in __getattr__
      self.data_files = self._get_data_files()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 82, in _get_data_files
      self.analyze_manifest()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 138, in analyze_manifest
      self.run_command('egg_info')
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 297, in run
      self.find_sources()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 304, in find_sources
      mm.run()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 535, in run
      self.add_defaults()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 571, in add_defaults
      sdist.add_defaults(self)
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
      self._add_defaults_ext()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
      build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
      cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
      self.finalize_options()
    File "C:\Users\murta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ir1pub43\fastparquet\setup.py", line 22, in finalize_options
      import numpy
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
      _win_os_check()
    File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
      raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
  RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\murta\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information:
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastparquet
  Running setup.py clean for fastparquet
Failed to build fastparquet
Installing collected packages: fastparquet
    Running setup.py install for fastparquet ... - ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\murta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ir1pub43\\fastparquet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\murta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ir1pub43\\fastparquet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\murta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b6q1790e\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\Include\fastparquet'
         cwd: C:\Users\murta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ir1pub43\fastparquet\
    Complete output (71 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running egg_info
    writing fastparquet.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to fastparquet.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to fastparquet.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to fastparquet.egg-info\top_level.txt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\murta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ir1pub43\fastparquet\setup.py", line 98, in <module>
        **extra
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 53, in run
        self.build_package_data()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 118, in build_package_data
        for package, src_dir, build_dir, filenames in self.data_files:
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 66, in __getattr__
        self.data_files = self._get_data_files()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 82, in _get_data_files
        self.analyze_manifest()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py", line 138, in analyze_manifest
        self.run_command('egg_info')
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 297, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 304, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 535, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 571, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "C:\Users\murta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ir1pub43\fastparquet\setup.py", line 22, in finalize_options
        import numpy
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
        _win_os_check()
      File "C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
        raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
    RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\murta\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information:
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\murta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ir1pub43\\fastparquet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\murta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ir1pub43\\fastparquet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\murta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b6q1790e\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\murta\Anaconda3\Include\fastparquet' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like Numpy update from 1.19.3 to 1.19.4 might be causing issues everywhere with dependencies. Something to look out for.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ongoing issue with `fastparquet` in relation to `Numpy 1.19.4`. Downgrading to `Numpy 1.19.3` helps to bypass the existing issue and install `fastparquet`.