# Scikit-bio installation error in windows 10 OS, "ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-bio"

Tags: python, windows, installation, skbio

I want to install scikit-bio in my windows 10 OS.
But whenever I ran the command `pip install scikit-bio`, I got the error message related with "Failed to building wheel for hdmedians".

I searched the similar questions, and upgraded pip(20.3), wheel(0.36.0) and setuptools(50.3.2) with up-to-date versions, but it did't work. I got the same message as followed

[image]

and after this error message, another error came

[image]

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Please add the errors as text to the question. Not as images

Comment: Okey I will. Anyway I solved the issue. I found 'error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2' in the respond, so I googled it and followed the guideline in the linke (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Yes. For me, the error of 'io.h' came with the errors I uploaded together, so the solutions were same as the link