# Unable to install tensornets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I was trying to install tensornets to run a python project on Windows. But when I do 'pip install tensornets' it shows the follow errors. What might be the problem?

I am running Python 3.8.7 on Windows 10 (21H1) PC

I tried to manually download the tensornets package and run the setup but got the similar erros.

Update: Answer available on - [Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

```
> pip install tensornets

Collecting tensornets
  Using cached tensornets-0.4.6.tar.gz (651 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  WARNING: Missing build requirements in pyproject.toml for tensornets from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/22/2c9402bbf142b94dc39d8a3c9884690ae87706a8bc1453d6cf0630525173/tensornets-0.4.6.tar.gz#sha256=e1095082b45a06168d56450d8c8fa49780d8aef8d4d1fcc64efceadb743f9ceb.
  WARNING: The project does not specify a build backend, and pip cannot fall back to setuptools without 'wheel'.
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: tensornets
  Building wheel for tensornets (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2_xce10z'
       cwd: C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2jm7e__7\tensornets_764656aa7ff64ef9bc4f6e22145fe9e5
  Complete output (88 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\capsulenets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\darknets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\densenets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\detections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\efficientnets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\inceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\layers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\middles.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\mobilenets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\nasnets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\ops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\preprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\pretrained.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\resnets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\squeezenets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\tnets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\unet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\version_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\vggs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\wavenets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\zf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  copying tensornets\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\datasets
  copying tensornets\datasets\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\datasets
  copying tensornets\datasets\imagenet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\datasets
  copying tensornets\datasets\voc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\datasets
  copying tensornets\datasets\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\datasets
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_framework
  copying tensornets\contrib_framework\arg_scope.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_framework
  copying tensornets\contrib_framework\variables.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_framework
  copying tensornets\contrib_framework\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_framework
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  copying tensornets\contrib_layers\initializers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  copying tensornets\contrib_layers\layers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  copying tensornets\contrib_layers\normalization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  copying tensornets\contrib_layers\optimizers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  copying tensornets\contrib_layers\regularizers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  copying tensornets\contrib_layers\rev_block_lib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  copying tensornets\contrib_layers\summaries.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  copying tensornets\contrib_layers\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  copying tensornets\contrib_layers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\contrib_layers
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references
  copying tensornets\references\rcnns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references
  copying tensornets\references\rpn_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references
  copying tensornets\references\yolos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references
  copying tensornets\references\yolo_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references
  copying tensornets\references\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\box.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  running egg_info
  writing tensornets.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to tensornets.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to tensornets.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'tensornets.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'tensornets.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\get_boxes.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\nms.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\datasets\coco.names -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\datasets
  copying tensornets\datasets\voc.names -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\datasets
  copying tensornets\references\coco.names -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references
  copying tensornets\references\voc.names -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\__init__.pyc -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\box.pyc -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\get_boxes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\get_boxes.so -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\nms.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\nms.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  copying tensornets\references\darkflow_utils\nms.so -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  running build_ext
  building 'tensornets.references.darkflow_utils.nms' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\tensornets
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\tensornets\references
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\tensornets\references\darkflow_utils
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5ydns0q8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tctensornets/references/darkflow_utils/nms.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\tensornets/references/darkflow_utils/nms.obj
  nms.c
  c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tensornets
Failed to build tensornets
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tensornets which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27io.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` so that the latest version of `wheel` is installled.

Comment: Updated. But the error is still the same.

Comment: Are you using a ```virtual environment```?

Comment: Yes. I updated the wheel on both the virtual environment as well as on system. I tried installing tensornets on both system wide and virtual env but I got the same error.