# C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, visual-studio, cython

I am trying to pack py code with  cython, however when I am running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, command prompt shows:

```
Anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I do have Visual Studio(2017 and 2019) and Build Tools as well; In the command prompt I did:

```
set LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt
set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt
```

before running python setup.py, also tried to run in the VS Studio Administrator: Windowds PowerShell and still the same issue.

And also when I am trying to run `%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat`command prompt shows:

```
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.
```

Comment: did you check the path for cl.exe?

Comment: yes, so when I am trying to open cl.exe it shows Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30133 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing Visual Studion Build Tools (it's an extra  command-line toolset you need to install)

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019

EDIT:

based on a thread found [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-8-vs2015-corecrt-h-error/45263/3) you should set this:

```
INCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits0\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt"
LIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits0\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits0\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86"
```

Comment: I have them, It's in my question : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools

Comment: did you check in the path?

`C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe`

Comment: visual Studio != Build Tools

Comment: when you click my link you need to scroll down till you see "Tools for Visual Studio 2019"

Comment: it shows that I have MSVC v142 -VS2019 C++ x65/86 build tools(latest)

Comment: never mind i did not read your error properly, its says you are missing io.h

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43998080/12239849 this guy solved it by adding the libs

Comment: yes, i added the lib in the command prompt it's still not running, I included it in my question

Comment: you need to add 2 paths, one ending with `ucrt\x64` and one with `\um\x64`

Comment: Yes, thank ypu, I added it before already, so what solved the issue that I also added System32 to the path and now it works. BUT another poblem appeared : python38.lib(python38.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1112

Comment: is there a folder? `ucrt\x68` ? in my computer it exists, so lib set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86`

Answer (score 0):

in command prompt before running `python setup.py install`, type:

```
INCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits0\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt"
LIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits0\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits0\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86"
```

also add these path to your 'edit environment variables for your account' as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits0\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits0\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits0\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86`

also if you have rights, then add C:\Windows\System32;
if you don't have rights(work computer etc), then run `python setup.py install` in command prompt, NOT anaconda prompt!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by :

1. install python-3.11.2-amd64.exe (to fix many prbl like err cl.exe code 2) and check if the problem gone if not go to the next steps :
2. download ***VISUAL COMMUNITY  2022*** installer
3. run .exe and pick **PYTHON DEVELOPMENT** in the left side
4. in the right side: pick and download **python native development tools** option
5. pick and download **python web option**
6. start downloading and installations
7. run pip install **setuptools**
8. run pip **--upgrade setuptools**
9. run pip install -your package-