# Cython compiler - fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory

Tags: compilation, cython

I really tried just about everything I found on the web including the StackOverflow answers to no avail..

When I'm running

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

to compile my Cython code, the error shows up:

```
C:\Users\irmsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include\pyconfig.h(59): fa
tal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Communit
y\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit sta
tus 2
```

Any ideas? I have tried:

1. Reinstalling Visual Strudio
2. Install ALL packages in Build tools
3. Adding some path variables
4. Running the compilation through Developer Command Prompt for VS

Comment: Have you been through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory? I think the "windows 10 SDK" is important, so I'd make absolutely sure that's included in the packages you've installed

Comment: Yes, I absolutely have

Comment: You need to look at the include paths when you are building. `io.h` is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\<version>\ucrt` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40810172/5769463) you must make sure that the path to the right run-time is used (by finding it on your disk and providing it if it is not picked up).