# Pipx failed to build packages

Tags: installation, brownie

When I run the command pipx install eth-brownie I receive the following error message,

```
fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    /Users/gentgjonbalaj/.local/pipx/logs/cmd_2021-10-22_11.10.14_pip_errors.log

pip failed to build package:
    cytoolz

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23087:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23092:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    cytoolz/functoolz.c:23176:19: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyGen_Send' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

I tried to use the command "pip install eth-brownie" but my terminal says "pip command not found."

Comment: Can you install with pipx instead of pip? Your life will be 10x better

Comment: @PatrickCollins That is the error after running the command: pipx install eth-brownie.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory/50210015#50210015

Comment: @PatrickCollins Unfortunately that did not help. I don't know if this helps but I entered the following prompt pip3 install eth-brownie and received the following error, Reason for being yanked: This version claims to support Python 2 but does not

Comment: How about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69783489/11969592

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I received the same error, and was finally able to resolve after running the following commands:

Using Homebrew:
brew install recordclass

brew install cython

xcrun codesign --sign - "/Users/jon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so"

pip3 install cytoolz

pip3 install pybind11

Comment: Installing cytoolz did it. Thank you!

Comment: `pip install cython
pip install cytoolz
pip install pybind11
pip install eth-brownie`

After these lines everything work fine!

Answer (score 4):

M1 Mac Chips has issues.  There are issues at 2 fronts.  (a) cytoolz, (b) regex==2021.10.8.

(a) cytoolz is resolved by doing pip install cytoolz and not pipx

(b) regex issue is a big one.  The issue is with the version.  Packaging bug causes an x86_64 regex to be installed on an Apple Silicon (M1) device (https://githubmemory.com/@dragos-vlad).  To fix this: Pinning regex to 2021.9.30 should work for the time being.  However for that you will have to change the requirements in the brownie git that you will use for installing.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Windows 10 I had the same issue, just had to run:

```
pip install Cython
```

then

```
pip install eth-brownie
```

For whatever reason I was finally able to install with pip but not with pipx.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem with python 3.10. Try `pyenv` and use python 3.9.1 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in Python 3.10 was installing cython and cytoolz before brownie.

Enter these three commands:

```
python3 -m pip install --user cython
python3 -m pip install --user cytoolz
python3 -m pip install --user eth-brownie
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Use pip rather than pipx.
command: pip install eth-brownie

Comment: It did not work either. I received the following warning, "Reason for being yanked: This version claims to support Python 2 but does not."

Comment: Then there is 1 more option to install brownie,
command - git clone https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie.git
cd brownie
python3 setup.py install

for more information, check out https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Python 3.10 on windows, simple run

```
 pip install eth-brownie
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I used pip3 install eth-brownie instead of pipx