# install web3.py error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, web3py

> install web3.py error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

```
(eth_env) D:\BaiduNetdiskWorkspace>pip install web3
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Collecting web3
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/c5/d6/e69cb31b3ea91309cc555cc779dd37b3344d387d66f4e608ffd07b2dac27/web3-5.24.0-py3-none-any.whl (487 kB)
Collecting eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.6
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/2d/6e/f664d592ed2a4879de450e1e88d64453c8dc6feeae080d1d2f21f2826c32/eth_account-0.5.6-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting protobuf<4,>=3.10.0
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/a0/5c/d8bae5c0e15945839a827b36d634bcfde091d8792cbeec76b130d8546aac/protobuf-3.19.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (895 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/f4/a2/28a7ec428c3f140ead2f3238814743e5eaf8be3c7dbf42a9551b11357691/aiohttp-3.7.4.post0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (635 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-typing<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from web3) (2.2.2)
Collecting lru-dict<2.0.0,>=1.1.6
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/68/ea/997af58d4e6da019ad825a412f93081d9df67e9dda11cfb026a3d7cd0b6c/lru-dict-1.1.7.tar.gz (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-utils<2.0.0,>=1.9.5 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from web3) (1.10.0)
Collecting ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/a0/ba/053527fbf8b3d75df19c8a6309f1f839c8ee721e4e36cfd966a0c83f6394/ipfshttpclient-0.8.0a2-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting websockets<10,>=9.1
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/f9/68/1e4a45c29466edbe4247917b22b8ced34a8b6766194cac84b860c9262039/websockets-9.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (90 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-abi<3.0.0,>=2.0.0b6 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from web3) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from web3) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from web3) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hexbytes<1.0.0,>=0.1.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from web3) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from web3) (228)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-hash[pycryptodome]<1.0.0,>=0.2.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from web3) (0.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: multiaddr>=0.0.7 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2->web3) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0->web3) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0->web3) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0->web3) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0->web3) (3.10.0.0)
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/e1/1e/5a4441be21b0726c4464f3f23c8b19628372f606755a9d2e46c187e65ec4/async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5.0,>=2.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0->web3) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parsimonious<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from eth-abi<3.0.0,>=2.0.0b6->web3) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-keys!=0.3.2,<0.4.0,>=0.2.1 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.6->web3) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-rlp<2,>=0.1.2 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.6->web3) (0.2.1)
Collecting bitarray<1.3.0,>=1.2.1
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/59/cd/cad4ea90820e58e4b46bc16b273d5928e09c3df467d3b10ad1f5a09c61d3/bitarray-1.2.2.tar.gz (48 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: rlp<3,>=1.0.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.6->web3) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-keyfile<0.6.0,>=0.5.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.6->web3) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycryptodome<4,>=3.6.6 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from eth-hash[pycryptodome]<1.0.0,>=0.2.0->web3) (3.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cytoolz<1.0.0,>=0.9.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from eth-keyfile<0.6.0,>=0.5.0->eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.6->web3) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from cytoolz<1.0.0,>=0.9.0->eth-keyfile<0.6.0,>=0.5.0->eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.6->web3) (0.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3) (52.0.0.post20210125)
Requirement already satisfied: varint in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2->web3) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: base58 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2->web3) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: netaddr in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2->web3) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (1.26.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in d:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (2.10)
Building wheels for collected packages: bitarray, lru-dict
  Building wheel for bitarray (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\EDZ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hugx1qez\\bitarray_53a143749edc4eca903fd5b486993ef1\\setup.p
y'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\EDZ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hugx1qez\\bitarray_53a143749edc4eca903fd5b486993ef1\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"
'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-x6pcl9d8'
       cwd: C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hugx1qez\bitarray_53a143749edc4eca903fd5b486993ef1\
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
  copying bitarray\test_bitarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
  copying bitarray\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
  copying bitarray\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
  copying bitarray\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
  running build_ext
  building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\bitarray
  cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\include -ID:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\includ
e\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbitarray/_bitarray.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\bitarray/_bitarray.obj
  error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bitarray
  Running setup.py clean for bitarray
  Building wheel for lru-dict (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\EDZ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hugx1qez\\lru-dict_9ed5c257ad6d478688d1c72ba5991612\\setup.p
y'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\EDZ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hugx1qez\\lru-dict_9ed5c257ad6d478688d1c72ba5991612\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"
'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-af0nujn8'
       cwd: C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hugx1qez\lru-dict_9ed5c257ad6d478688d1c72ba5991612\
  Complete output (9 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'lru' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\include -ID:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\includ
e\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tclru.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\lru.obj
  error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
Failed to build bitarray lru-dict
Installing collected packages: bitarray, async-timeout, websockets, protobuf, lru-dict, ipfshttpclient, eth-account, aiohttp, web3
    Running setup.py install for bitarray ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\EDZ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hugx1qez\\bitarray_53a143749edc4eca903fd5b486993ef1\\setup
.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\EDZ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hugx1qez\\bitarray_53a143749edc4eca903fd5b486993ef1\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h1m6lyoe\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\so
ftwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\Include\bitarray'
         cwd: C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hugx1qez\bitarray_53a143749edc4eca903fd5b486993ef1\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
    copying bitarray\test_bitarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
    copying bitarray\test_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
    copying bitarray\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
    copying bitarray\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\bitarray
    running build_ext
    building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\bitarray
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\include -ID:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x8
6)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\incl
ude\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbitarray/_bitarray.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\bitarray/_bitarray.obj
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\EDZ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hugx1qez\\bitarray_53a143
749edc4eca903fd5b486993ef1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\EDZ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hugx1qez\\bitarray_53a143749edc4eca903fd5b486993ef1\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=
f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\EDZ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h1m6lyoe\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed -
-compile --install-headers 'D:\softwares\anaconda3\envs\eth_env\Include\bitarray' Check the logs for full command output.
```

My python version: 3.8.5

I have already install Microsoft C++ 14.0 and Win10 SDK, Win8 SDK, it still didn't work.

The error message is a little long this is the last message it gives

> error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

Comment: Now i use the Visual Studio C++ Bulid Tools to reinstall Win8.1 SDK and Win10 SDK, maybe it got be done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50210015/15807017 Follow this. Got Done

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)