# Unable to install LDA in windows

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, installation, lda

I am trying to install LDA for a python project on windows.
I am running "pipenv install lda" inside the virtual environment of the project but I am facing an error.
It seems to be an error related to the 'io.h' file.

```
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal 
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' 
failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------"
```

I have python 3.8 installed and I have already installed these below packages:
[packages]

```
gensim = "==3.8.3"
pandas = "==1.0.5"
nltk = "==3.5"
numpy = "==1.18.5"
mongoengine = "==0.22.1"
scikit-learn = "==0.24.0"
Flask = "==1.1.2"
sqlalchemy = "*"
pymysql = "*"
requests = "*"
spacy = "~=3.0"
matplotlib = "*"
networkx = "*"
sudo = "*"
pip = "*"
```

I have tried many things but it's not working. Has anyone got any idea about this?

Update:I have tried things mentioned in the suggested article, the 'io.h' error seems to be solved, however, now a new error is popping up "build\lib.win32-3.8\lda_lda.cp38-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 160 unresolved externals error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120 ---------------------------------------- –"
Also, I am doing this in Developer Command Prompt VS 2022

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Yes, I tried that.. installed windows 10 sdk and vs build tools. but still, the same issue

Comment: Did you read all the answers in that post?

Comment: Yes, now the problem is ,     build\lib.win32-3.8\lda\_lda.cp38-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 160 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
    ----------------------------------------