# Issues while installing web3py

Tags: python, web3py

I'm encountering following error while installing web3py:

```
Running setup.py install for cytoolz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Software\Environment\Python3.9.9\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ROG\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-eeqwacua\\cytoolz_7064e08653b9422cbd2203110a2138b4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ROG\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-eeqwacua\\cytoolz_7064e08653b9422cbd2203110a2138b4\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-smsq3qy1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\Software\Environment\Python3.9.9\Include\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-eeqwacua\cytoolz_7064e08653b9422cbd2203110a2138b4\
    Complete output (56 lines):
    ALERT: Cython not installed.  Building without Cython.
    running install
    D:\Software\Environment\Python3.9.9\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cytoolz
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -ID:\Software\Environment\Python3.9.9\include -ID:\Software\Environment\Python3.9.9\include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include" /Tccytoolz/dicttoolz.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\cytoolz/dicttoolz.obj
    dicttoolz.c
    D:\Software\Environment\Python3.9.9\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Can not open file include: “io.h”: No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\Software\Environment\Python3.9.9\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ROG\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-eeqwacua\\cytoolz_7064e08653b9422cbd2203110a2138b4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ROG\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-eeqwacua\\cytoolz_7064e08653b9422cbd2203110a2138b4\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ROG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-smsq3qy1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\Software\Environment\Python3.9.9\Include\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: In accordance with [ask], please research your inquiry before posting here. Duplicate of [Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes for this error. The most common causes are

- Incorrect specified file names
- The file is not present in the include search path
- The file may be locked or in use

If none of these issues seem to be applicable in your case, the file could be in your project, but not the include search path