# Can't install module "Bio" in PyCharm/VirtualStudio, neither using cmd (Windows)

Tags: python, biopython

I'm new to using Python and after months of not using PyCharm and VirtualStudio. I needed to do some Python stuff. I don't know why, but I can't load and install any module.
I need Bio module and I can't install it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRNsw.png)

I tried to install it by cmd command using:

- C:\Python310\python.exe -m pip install Biopython
- pip install Biopython
- Other pip commands, but I got the same error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cQju.png)

And this happened. I installed VisualStudio from Windows, but I can't install it yet.

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory