# How do I solve this Error when installing Web3 library using pip

Tags: python, pycharm, web3py

I am trying to install Web3 library using 'pip install web3'. Pycharm and Windows

This is the error I get:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: lru-dict, bitarray, cytoolz
  Building wheel for lru-dict (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      error: Unable to find a compatible Visual Studio installation.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
  Building wheel for bitarray (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

(it does the same error for the other packages: bitarray and cytoolz)
```

It says cannot find compatible Visual Studio but I have it installed, as well as visual c++.

Comment: What version of visual c++ are you using?

Comment: I pretty much have them all, but latest I have installed is 14.29.30139

Comment: Try installing the latest [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build+tools)

Comment: I already did, still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to find an answer:

[Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory/56811119#56811119)

**MAKE SURE YOU REBOOT PC**

This solved the problem for me.
Thank you guys for helping