# i got error installing cython for windows. how to fix this issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

these are the errors when i try to do `pip install -e git+https://github.com/samson-wang/cython_bbox.git#egg=cython-bbox`

python 3.10.8

how to fix this issue:

```
(venv) PS D:\Elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\easy-yolov7> pip install -e git+https://github.com/samson-wang/cython_bbox.git#egg=cython-bbox
Obtaining cython-bbox from git+https://github.com/samson-wang/cython_bbox.git#egg=cython-bbox
  Updating d:\elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\src\cython-bbox clone
  Running command git fetch -q --tags
  Running command git reset --hard -q 17a9209162d2107c1d2d17ea66fb2a3c7fa0c73e
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in d:\elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\lib\site-packages (from cython-bbox) (0.29.33)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in d:\elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\lib\site-packages (from cython-bbox) (1.23.5)
Installing collected packages: cython-bbox
  Running setup.py develop for cython-bbox
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [23 lines of output]
        running develop
        D:\Elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is
 deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
          warnings.warn(
        D:\Elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated
. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
          warnings.warn(
        running egg_info
        writing cython_bbox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to cython_bbox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
        writing requirements to cython_bbox.egg-info\requires.txt
        writing top-level names to cython_bbox.egg-info\top_level.txt
        reading manifest file 'cython_bbox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
        adding license file 'LICENSE'
        writing manifest file 'cython_bbox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        running build_ext
        skipping 'src\cython_bbox.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
        building 'cython_bbox' extension
        D:\vs\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-ID:\Elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\lib\site-packages\
numpy\core\include" "-ID:\Elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\include" -IC:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\user\AppData\
Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\vs\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -ID:\vs\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include /Tcsrc\cython_bbox.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpyt
hon-310\Release\src\cython_bbox.obj gcc
        cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'gcc', object file assumed
        cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'gcc' ignored
        cython_bbox.c
        C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or director
y
        error: command 'D:\\vs\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
        [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [23 lines of output]
    running develop
    D:\Elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is dep
recated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    D:\Elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Us
e build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running egg_info
    writing cython_bbox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to cython_bbox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to cython_bbox.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to cython_bbox.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'cython_bbox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    adding license file 'LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'cython_bbox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    skipping 'src\cython_bbox.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'cython_bbox' extension
    D:\vs\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-ID:\Elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\lib\site-packages\nump
y\core\include" "-ID:\Elpark camera test-- kims\ocr-live\venv\include" -IC:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\user\AppData\Loca
l\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -ID:\vs\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -ID:\vs\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include /Tcsrc\cython_bbox.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-
310\Release\src\cython_bbox.obj gcc
    cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'gcc', object file assumed
    cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'gcc' ignored
    cython_bbox.c
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory   
    error: command 'D:\\vs\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its a bug in  cython_bbox package itself when compiling that in windows.

Comment: ok so how to fix this?

Comment: File a bug report and hope for the best  or learn how to do compilations ? issue is on this line: https://github.com/samson-wang/cython_bbox/blame/17a9209162d2107c1d2d17ea66fb2a3c7fa0c73e/setup.py#L33  .. "gcc" gets passed to msvc's cl.exe as-is and it is not valid argument (it gets interpreted as "file that needs to be compiled" ..  Even the point that author added "gcc" specifically for windows side of things hints that even if you fix that issue, rest of the codebase might not compile ..

Comment: also, your visualstudio might not have all the needed header files, another error is missing io.h file .. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory helps ?