# Getting this error when trying to install pyrevolve

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

Please find the entire text output after pip install pyrevolve, have tried downgrading and upgrading different versions of Python and have also tried to uninstall anaconda but doesn't seem to be very useful.

```
 Collecting pyrevolve
  Using cached pyrevolve-2.2.3.tar.gz (254 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: contexttimer in c:\users\usermain\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyrevolve) (0.3.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyrevolve
  Building wheel for pyrevolve (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      copying pyrevolve\compression.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      copying pyrevolve\custom_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      copying pyrevolve\logger.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      copying pyrevolve\profiling.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      copying pyrevolve\pyrevolve.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      copying pyrevolve\storage.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      copying pyrevolve\tools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      copying pyrevolve\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      copying pyrevolve\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve\schedulers
      copying pyrevolve\schedulers\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve\schedulers
      copying pyrevolve\schedulers\crevolve.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve\schedulers
      copying pyrevolve\schedulers\hrevolve.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve\schedulers
      copying pyrevolve\schedulers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve\schedulers
      UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve/_version.py
      set build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pyrevolve/_version.py to '2.2.3'
      running build_ext
      building 'pyrevolve.crevolve' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\pyrevolve
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\pyrevolve\schedulers
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I. -Ipyrevolve -IC:\Users\Usermain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\Usermain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include /EHsc /Tppyrevolve/schedulers/crevolve.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\pyrevolve/schedulers/crevolve.obj
      crevolve.cpp
```

```
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyrevolve
  Running setup.py clean for pyrevolve
Failed to build pyrevolve
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyrevolve, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Had tried few other things like trying to install it through conda, updating conda and also updating Python versions but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is your Python version?

Comment: Version : Python 3.9.13

Comment: Please [edit] and show us the full text output starting from the command `pip install pyrevolve` and down to the last line.

Comment: Done, added the entire text output

Comment: If the error (lost in the chain of editing) is "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory" than it's well-known: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50210015/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22fatal+error+C1083%22+%22Cannot+open+include+file%3A+io.h+No+such+file+or+directory%22

Comment: You seem to have cut off the error message to very precisely omit just the crucial part.

Comment: it tries to compile some `C/C++` code and probably it needs some other `C/C++` library (or header files `*.h`) but you didn't show FULL error message so we don't know what library you may need. Reinstalling Python can't help because it needs C/C++ files which you have to install separately (they are not part of Python)

Comment: From a Conda perspective: 1) probably sufficient if you make sure the starting environment has `cython` installed (that will guarantee functional compilers) 2) better would just be to [add it to Conda Forge](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/adding_pkgs.html) (or [ask that it be added](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Package+request&projects=&template=package-request.yml&title=Package+request%3A+)) so you don't have to local compile in the first place.